# how to change error logging location without modifying code in C# application?

Tags: c#, nlog, file-location, exception-logging

I used `Nlog` for logging exceptions in my C# windows application and had a file called `LogConfig.cs` which has all the details about the location (path) and file name where to store these exceptions.

Now if I want to change the location where these files are getting logged I need to modify the code. Is there a way to change the location where the exceptions get logged without changing the code ?

I am trying to avoid a build into production just for changing the path where locations are getting saved.

Is storing this info (path and file name) in a separate text file and reading from it the best way to do it. That way I can just modify the text file in production and there would be no need for a code change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all your logging configuration, including paths, to [NLog.config](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file) , and place it in the same folder as your exe file. It will be loaded automatically and applied by NLog.